# How can projects or datasets inside projects of GoodData be filtered among project users?

Tags: filter, dataset, gooddata

How can projects or datasets inside projects of GoodData be filtered among project users. I know the following two ways.

1. Attribute Filter Variables
   https://support.gooddata.com/entries/23354962-Setting-Up-Numerical-and-Filtered-Variables
2. Mandatory User Filters
   http://developer.gooddata.com/article/mandatory-user-filters-for-beginners

Are there any ways other than the above two and how if there are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two are correct ways. The first one is for assigning some constant or attribute value to specific user for Report computation. The second one (Mandatory User Filters) are based on specific data values - assigned to user in GoodData Project. You can define rules so that only selected user can see specific data.

Example:
*Human resources department can see only data related to their Department, not others.*

Do you have any specific use case? Let me know!